# Submit a form by clicking on a <li> in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, forms

I'm getting a form from a database and I want to let the user pick an answer just by clicking on it. I'm working on Django so I have this template code:

```
<form id="game" action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="{{ question.id }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="answer">
  <ul class="list1-g">

    {% for answer in form.answers %}
      <li class="list-g-a" data-answer="1">
        <p class="answ">{{ answer }}</p>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}

  </ul>
</form>
```

I tried this picking an answer and copying the answer value into the hidden field, but with this jQuery code I got no result.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#game li').click(function() {
         $('input[name="answer"]').val($(this).data('answer'));
         $('#game').submit();
    });
});
```

Having in mind that when I call {{ answer }} it returns four answers (or in some cases 2), what should I fix to make it work?

This form works according to forms.py:

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, question, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        choice_list = [x for x in question.get_answers_list()]
        self.fields["answers"] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choice_list,
                                                   widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

I'm here to respond further questions about the code or the purpose. Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please explain what you mean by `Having in mind that when I call {{ answer }} it returns four answers (or in some cases 2), what should I fix to make it work?` What does `{{ answer }}` output in the HTML?

Comment: I mean that generally the {{answer}} call returns four answers, each one in its <li> element. I want that, by clicking on the <li> (or <p>) it submits the form.

Comment: Could you show the actual HTML output. If `{{ answer }}` outputs `li` elements then your HTML will be invalid and you'll have that issue to solve first.

Comment: I edited the first post with the forms.py snippet. Is it wrong the output ? I have to say the output {{answer}} show is the correct one, being the answers asociated to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I run your javascript code in codepen and builds and makes the post correctly.

It may not be working with django because your `data-anwser` attr is always equals to 1.

You need to do something like:

```
{% for answer in form.answers %}
  <li class="list-g-a" data-answer="{{answer.index}}">
    <p class="answ">{{ answer }}</p>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thought about that but can't find a way to do it since the answers have not any id. Thank you

Comment: Well, in the end you can put there whatever you want, `data-answer="{{answers}}"` would work. But you have to tell the form how to manage it, i.e. get the form data and create the objects you need

Comment: How would it interpret {{answers}} if it's not defined? It doesn't work as when it was data-answer="1". Any clue on how to tell the form how to manage it...? Being a bit desperated with this, thank you very much

Comment: Since you are not doing some tweaking in the form, you'll need to handle the form in the view [as in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form).

Comment: Another option is to use a `ChoiceField` (which works great with class based views and modelForms), get the values from there to generate the <li> elements. And when clicking in the li, select the proper option in the select and submit the form

Comment: Well in forms.py you can see I'm actually using ChoiceField, but I'm not sure to exactly understand and code what you mean... thank you however the help is appreciated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112309/discussion-between-kiril-and-jim).

Answer (score 0):

not sure about django but you should be able to do something like this:

```
 <li class="list-g-a" onclick="function() { myfunction(1);}" data-answer="1">
    <p class="answ">{{ answer }}</p>
  </li>
```

and in js :

```
function myfunction(value) {
        ....
    });
```